# fancyBox/JQuery Callback Not Working

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have seen the various examples on here of how to use the afterClose callback with Fancybox.  I have tried several variations of this code and none are firing the alert after using the "X" to close the shadowbox.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".receipt").fancybox({
        type : 'ajax',
        href : 'https://www.docuvital.com/index.cfm/receipt/', 
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        nextEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        prevEffect  : 'elastic',
        openSpeed   : 1000,
        nextSpeed   : 1000,
        closeSpeed  : 1500,
        prevSpeed   : 1000,
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : true,
        closeClick  : false,
        autoCenter  : true,
        scrolling   : 'no',
        helpers : {  
            overlay : { 
                closeClick: false,
                css : { 'background' : 'rgba(150,144,146,.60)'},
                      }
                  },
    afterClose: function(){
        alert("done");
    }
}).trigger("click"); // triggers fancybox on page load so no need $.fancybox.open
}); // ready
</script>
```

Comment: you have two fancybox bounds to the same selector when normally needs only one. The second by the way (which would override the first) is outside the `.ready()` method so this might be the reason is not working.

Comment: Could you give me the correct code to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all your fancybox initializations should be inside the `.ready()` method AND you need a single one for the same selector.

**EDIT** :

To simplify the code, you may **not** need `$.fancybox.open()` but triggering the `click` on page load :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // $(".receipt").fancybox(); // this is redundant
    $(".receipt").fancybox({
        // ALL my API options here
        // then my callback
        afterClose: function(){
            // do something here
            alert("done");
        }
    }).trigger("click"); // triggers fancybox on page load so no need $.fancybox.open
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tG29Y/)**

**EDIT #2** : using `$.fancybox.open()` method with your code (that also works!!!)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // $(".receipt").fancybox(); // this is redundant because you don't have a link
    $.fancybox.open({
        type: 'iframe', // ajax but switched to iframe for testing
        href: 'http://jsfiddle.net',
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        nextEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        prevEffect: 'elastic',
        openSpeed: 1000,
        nextSpeed: 1000,
        closeSpeed: 1500,
        prevSpeed: 1000,
        maxWidth: 800,
        maxHeight: 600,
        fitToView: false,
        width: '70%',
        height: '70%',
        autoSize: true,
        closeClick: false,
        autoCenter: true,
        scrolling: 'no',
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                closeClick: false,
                css: {
                    'background': 'rgba(150,144,146,.60)'
                }
            }
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            alert("done");
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HHKcq/)**

Comment: yes, i get this part, but i stil don't understand how to combine my $.fancybox.open and specify the afterClose as well....

Comment: Does `$.fancybox.open` open the same as `$(".receipt")`?

Comment: yes, it opens the shadowbox which is the receipt, on closing that box, i want to fire my code

Comment: @MichaelPayne : see my edited answer and demo. PS. is not shadowbox but fancybox ;)

Comment: See my edited code in the original post.  It does not work.  Dreamweaver gives javascript error.  Also, your JSFiddle uses HTML to place the image.  In my example, there is not HTML, it needs to auto open on pageload with just javascript.

Comment: @MichaelPayne : my jsfiddle is just an example about how to use and wrap the code, is not a cooking recipe. The issue with your code (the js error) is because you missed the comma `,` to separate the `afterClose` callback from the preceding `helpers` option (after the curly closing bracket of the `helpers` option to be more explicit)

Comment: duhh -- ooops :) I knew that!  The error is gone, but the code is now not firing on page load.  How can the trigger("click") work if there is no click.  I need it to fire on page load, and it's not.

Comment: @MichaelPayne : `.trigger("click")` does, actually, trigger a click. Check my jsfiddle (which actually triggers the click on page load) and compare it with your code to see what you might be doing wrong (I don't have more time to dig into this issue, which from my point of view is case closed ;)

Comment: @MichaelPayne : you also need an anchor like `<a class="receipt" ...` to be triggered, do you have one? if so, it should have an `href` so you may need to remove this line from your code `href : 'https://www.docuvital.com/index.cfm/receipt/',`

Comment: I was just about to write about your last comment... there is no HTML (ie.e anchor..etc).... the beauty of the $.fancybox.open is that it DOES NOT require the anchor, which I have no use for... as I'm only using the fancybox (no image/link is actually on the page).  I got your code to work, but I had to add a basically fake <a> tag.  IT would be nice (and cleaner) if this would work with the $.fancybox.open.

Comment: @MichaelPayne : if you don't have an anchor, then there is not need of `$(".receipt").fancybox()` so you were setting the callback in the wrong place ... it should be in your `$.fancybox.open()` then (what a waste of time)

Comment: I tried the callback in the $.fancybox.open()... that is the very first thing i tried...and exactly the type of solution i was looing for.... with no luck

Comment: @MichaelPayne : see my last edit (and this is my last comment too)

Comment: this was the very first thing i tried before i posted here, but i was missing a comma...thanks for all your help